# AWS Glue - PySpark DF to Redshift - How to handle columns with null values

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, null, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue to load MongoDB data to AWS Redshift. Below is the process -

1. Read from a Mongo collection.
2. Create a Spark DF - this contains some columns with **all or some** null values.
3. Write to a Redshift table - using a JDBC driver - v2.1.0.9

When I load the data to the Redshift table it has the below error -

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver not capable
```

Upon further research, we found that this is a bug of the JDBC driver -

1. https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-jdbc-driver/issues/27
2. https://repost.aws/questions/QU5XgZTUmZTmOSfUUWIqDYFA/aws-glue-loading-into-redshift-with-empty-values

We are not sure how long will it take to fix the bug. Currently, we are storing 'Null' as a string and later updating it with Null. But this is an additional step which we want to avoid.

Can someone please suggest any workaround for this?

Thank you!

Sanket Kelkar

**Edit1** - as suggested by @Robert Kossendey
We tried to convert a few columns from `NullType()` to `StringType()` using

```
for field in df.schema.fields:
    if isinstance(field.dataType, NullType):
        df = df.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).cast(StringType()))
```

but still got the same error. Any thoughts?

**Edit2** - Added sample DF that I am trying to load to Redshift - The null here are the actual Nulls and not the string "Null"

```
+--------------------+---------+--------+---------+-----+----------+
|                  id|firstName|lastName|languages|title|isInActive|
+--------------------+---------+--------+---------+-----+----------+
|96bb3341-5e9c-11e...|   Test12| Support|     null| null|      null|
|b9289c00-a5b6-11e...|      Ind|   Admin|  English| null|     false|
|b9289c00-a5b6-11e...|      Ind|   Admin|   French| null|     false|
|fd077cc0-a5b6-11e...|      Moh|   Admin|  English| null|     false|
|fd077cc0-a5b6-11e...|      Moh|   Admin|   French| null|     false|
+--------------------+---------+--------+---------+-----+----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Glue / Spark you just need to make sure that there are no columns with the type `NullType()`.

You can still have a column with `StringType()` that contains `null / None`.
Just cast your `NullType()` columns to a supported column type.

Comment: Can you please check my Edit1 in the original question? We tried converting the columns from `NullType()` to `StringType()` but getting the same error.

Comment: Could you provide the schema of the DF that you are writing + some example data on which the insert fails? Also are you creating a new table or writing into an existing?

Comment: Not sure why I am not able to add a separate comment :(, so I have edited my original question again. Please refer to **Edit2**. 
I am writing into an existing table.